# HTML image tag seems like have some margin or padding

Tags: html

I am currently working on a new porfolio website development, now I'm the development stage and started walking at a problem. It seems that all image tags a small margin or padding on the bottom have 4px to be exact. I have all the margins and padding to 0 put, but this is not resolved. How to solve this?

I love to hear from you.

Comment: have you tried `img {padding:0; margin:0;}` in the css? can you show us some code?

Comment: do you have a link? or some code?

Comment: can you tell us if you are using a specific browser? have checked parent containers' margins?

Comment: This is the code for all the images: `img {
 max-width: 100%;
}
img, a img {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
}`
I have one small question, I doubt whether `img a` well formulated and that it's not `a img` should be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images typically will be vertically aligned with the baseline of text, which causes a bit of spacing at the bottom. Using `vertical-align: middle` or `vertical-align: top` should fix this issue.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/JgA5F/2/

Comment: Thank you very much. This will fix my issue! What is the best one top or middle, and is this good for setting for all img tags or should you advice only to images that it should applied to? @zzzzBov

Comment: "best" depends on how you're using the images. As the example shows, text will be aligned with whichever one you've chosen. I tend to use `vertical-align: top` globally, but there are cases where you may want to middle align images (very common with icons in links).